# How can i get default values set in woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

Woocommerce has a class for countries and states, i want to use it on a custom page.
i only want the countries in an array, found this function on woo commerce docs, but it is not returning anything and crashing my site.

```
global $woocommerce;

$countries   = $woocommerce->get_countries();
```

i also tired this post but it seems to be not compatible with the current version:
[How to get woocommerce country select dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046974/how-to-get-woocommerce-country-select-dropdown)

```
global $woocommerce;

$countries_obj   = new WC_Countries();
$countries   = $countries_obj->get_countries();
```

also did not work, i also checked the log it is telling me:
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_countries()

Comment: By "custom page" you mean something completely outside of WordPress? Then you need to load WP functionality first (including wp-load.php), and after that you might either need to embed necessary WC files manually, or maybe put your code inside a right hook, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208076/use-woocommerce-function-in-other-wordpress-plugin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31048171/1906356 may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
global $woocommerce;
$countries_obj   = new WC_Countries();
$countries   = $countries_obj->__get('countries');

array('options' => $countries);
```

this solved it, i was not converting the results